# Is the resemblance between Glen and David Bowie (c. Ziggy Stardust) intentional?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, inspiration, childs-play

In the movie *Seed of Chucky*, Chucky's offspring Glen/Glenda bears a striking resemblance to David Bowie during the *Ziggy Stardust*/*Aladdin Sane* era of his career.

[image]

Beyond the physical similarities, he also shares some character traits with Bowie, including a British nationality, and a tendency towards gender-bending.

Has anyone involved in the film revealed that this was a deliberate decision, or is it simple coincidence?

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Before anyone asks, yes, *Child's Play* is certainly on topic, since the central premise of the series revolves around black magic and voodoo.

Comment: They don't look much alike to me...

Comment: Ghostly pale.  Red spiky hair.  Narrow noses.  No eyebrows.  Pronounced brow ridges.  Strong cheekbones.  Slightly sunken eyes.  Broad foreheads.  Eyes far apart.  Indecision and uncertainty regarding gender identity.

Comment: YMMV, of course.

Comment: @randal'thor - See it now, in the new pictures?

Comment: @randal'thor  Whoever made the photo comparison was dumb.  An ugly doll should be compared with an ugly picture of Bowie, not a glamour shot.

Comment: I am with @randal'thor on this one: Bowie is rocking a mullet, vivid lipstick matching the hair, narrow eyes (leaving out the unique pupil thing he has in the left eye due to a childhood accident), ultra-glam fashion wear, jewelry, and a slightly cleft chin. None of which Glen is rocking. Also I would totes magotes go for hot make out times with Ziggy Stardust Bowie, but no friggin' way for the psychotic puppet.

Comment: Actually, nope, I still don't see it. For a while I thought the two images in the 2nd row were the two different people/characters rather than the same one!

Comment: I can see the resemblance. It would also fit with the black-comedy aspect of the *Chucky* franchise. The resemblance is also noted in the comments section of [this IMDB review.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387575/reviews)

Comment: According to the [Childs Play Wikia](http://childsplay.wikia.com/wiki/Glenda) (because of course there is one), "The inspiration for the gender-confused child Glen, was the 1953 film "Glen or Glenda"." No source is given for this, though.

Comment: @JoeL. - I'm guessing that they mean the character's gender identity is based on Glen or Glenda, since bot movies feature a main character who calls himself/herself first one, then the other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Screenwriter and Director Don Mancini states that while Glen/Glenda resembles David Bowie/Ziggy Stardust, there is no intentional reference.

A [CampBlood](http://campblood.org/Features/Don%20Mancini.htm) exclusive interview with Don Mancini:

> Was the Glen doll in Seed modeled after Mia Farrow? Seriously...
>
> Glen has also been compared to David Bowie/Ziggy Stardust, as well as
>   to Lucille Ball. **I was going for a Tim Burton or Edward Gorey sort of**
>   **look** -- monstrous yet innocent. I suppose that description could apply
>   to all of the above -- but I have my doubts about Mia Farrow's
>   innocence.

In a separate interview with [NYMag](http://nymag.com/nymetro/movies/features/10317/), Don Mancini states that he wanted to make Glen gay.  He also states that the only point of reference used is the Ed Wood film *Glen and Glenda*:

> You’ve said that Universal passed on the script for Seed of Chucky
>   because they felt it was “too gay.”
>
> Well, people have expectations for the fifth movie in a slasher
>   series.
>
> What did they expect?
>
> Son of Chucky, another killer doll. I thought it’s much more
>   interesting if the child is completely sweet and innocent and wants
>   nothing to do with that activity. The bottom line is, **“What if Chucky
>   had a gay kid?”** To me, that’s hilarious.
>
> Do you reference other coming-out tales?
>
> **No. Only Glen or Glenda, the Ed Wood film.** I wanted this one to be
>   more like Ordinary People, very character- and dialogue-driven.

Comment: I'm a bit horrified that the director had the nerve to compare this pile of crap with *Ordinary People*.